# CSRF error on file upload view (CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.)

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I'm trying to build a page with an upload form in Django and the GET request works fine but when I send the file I get the following error: `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted`.

My view is very simple:

```
class ImportView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'assignments/import.html'
    form_class = ImportForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('assignment_import')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            # handle upload here
            assignments = pd.read_excel(request.FILES['file'].file)
            for i, assignment in assignments.iterrows():
                assignment_obj = Assignment()
                assignment_obj.name = assignment['name']
                assignment_obj.save()

            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

And the form template (`assignments/import.html`):

```
<h2>Import assignments</h2>
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{{ form.source.errors }}
{{ form.source }}
<form class="post-form assignments-import" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row flexibel" style="clear: left;">
    <div class="col">{{ form.file|add_class:form.file.name|as_crispy_field }}</div>
  </div>
  <button class="save btn btn-success" type="submit">Assignment</button>
</form>
```

In my `settings.py` I have (the relevant parts):

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('DJANGO_SECRET', default='...')
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '.example.com']

MAPS_URL = os.getenv('MAPS_URL', default="https://www.example.com")
DOMAIN_NAME = os.getenv('DOMAIN_NAME', default=".example.com")

# Production settings
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = True
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = True
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = True
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = DOMAIN_NAME
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = DOMAIN_NAME
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = DOMAIN_NAME
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.getenv('STATIC_ROOT', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.getenv('MEDIA_ROOT', Path(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')).resolve())
```

When I comment the "production settings" part out I don't get the error (but I do get an error in the shiftleft-scan check I do). Any idea how I can fix this in a safe manner (I don't want to disable CSRF validation, that seems like an unsafe thing to do)?

Comment: Is your `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` setting correct? Going to that is your setting for `DOMAIN_NAME` correct?

Comment: I have set it to `localhost` to test locally, that doesn't work..

Comment: For development just keep the setting as `None` so `os.getenv('DOMAIN_NAME', default=None)`

Comment: Thanks Abdul! It now works (I thought it was set to localhost, but it wasn't in the end...)